# Show that $\cosh(x)\leq e^x$ for all $x\in[0,\infty[$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

> Show that $\cosh(x)\leq e^x$ for all $x\in[0,\infty[$.

**My approach:**

We know that both series converge and have the Taylor series expansion at $x=0$ given by

\begin{align*}
&\cosh(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}\\
&e^x=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}.
\end{align*}

We assume $k\geq \lceil x\rceil$ and see
$$
\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}\cdot \frac{k!}{x^k}=\frac{x^k}{2k\cdot(2k-1)\cdot(2k-2)\cdots (k+1)}\leq\frac{k^k}{(k+1)^k}\leq 1\implies \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}\leq \frac{x^k}{k!}.
$$
This shows that
$$
\sum\limits_{k=\lceil x\rceil}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}\leq \sum\limits_{k=\lceil x\rceil}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}.
$$
I am not sure how to argue correctly w.r.t. the remaining $\lceil x\rceil$-many members of both series. Intuitively I would simply say that an infinite amount of summands of $\sum\limits_{k=\lceil x\rceil}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}$ that are greater simply outweight the finite many summands of $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\lceil x\rceil}\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}$ that *may* be greater then $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\lceil x\rceil}\frac{x^k}{k!}$.

---

Is this correct? How would you deal with the last issue?

Comment: Why run them out to the same number of positive terms, instead of (more naturally) running them out to the same degree?

Comment: It's far easier if you use the definition $\cosh(x)=(e^x + e^{-x})/2$

Comment: Another possibility: Every term in the Taylor series for $\cosh(x)$ also appears in $e^x$, and the additional terms in $e^x$ are all positive when $x\geq 0$.

Comment: $$\cosh(x)-e^x=-\sinh(x)\le 0$$ for $x\ge 0$

Answer (score 4):

Easier solution:

For $x\geq 0$, the following is true: $e^x\geq e^{-x}$. Thus,

$$\cosh(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2} \leq \frac{e^x+e^x}{2}=e^x$$